# Border columns histogram R

Tags: r

I want to create a histogram in R.
My code is:

```
hist(P1_Pre_Benefits, main="Pre survey Benefits", xlab="", 
     col="lightgreen", breaks=c(0.5,1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5), xaxt="n", xlim=c(1, 6), ylim=c(0, 45))

 axis(side=1, at=seq(1, 5, 1), 
      labels=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

This works, however, the first bar is too close to the y axis, I would like a space here. Anyone know how to solve this?

[image: current output]

Comment: Try `xlim=c(0, 6)`. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Also, are you only interested in base R answers, or would answers using other packages, like ggplot2, be acceptable?

Comment: Thank you so much, that was so easy to solve!